# Prove it is a markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm given a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ that verifies the following recursion
$X_{n+1} = (X_n + Y_n - K)^+ +Z_n$ where:

$Y_n$ is a sequence of iid poisson random variables of paramater $\lambda_1 d_1$

$(Z_n)$ is a sequence of iid random variables of parameter $\lambda_1(d_2 + 2L/v)$

$K $ is an integer

Both sequences $(Y_n) and (Z_n)$ are independent.

I have to show that $(X_n)$ is a markov chain.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is your definition of a Markov chain?  For example a sequence of random variables with the Markov property? Or something else as well?  How does your recursion fit with this definition?

Comment: $(X_n)$  designates the number of cars in a queue at moment n.   I'm using  the following definition  $(X_n)$ is a Markov chain if $P(X_{n+1} = x |X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, .... X_n = x_n) = P(X_{n+1} =x | X_n = x_n) $

Comment: $X_{n+1} = (X_n + Y_n - K)^+ +Z_n$ does not seem to have anything earlier than time $n$ since $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ and $K$ are independent of anything earlier

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this. How do we know that $(Y_n)$ and  $(Z_n)$ and K are independent of anything earlier ?

Comment: Constants are independent of everything and you said the $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ are iid sequences

Comment: hmm what does this means ? If Y_n and Z_n and K are independent does that mean we are left with X_n ?

Comment: So $X_{n+1}$ depends solely on the value of $X_n$ and some new stuff. This is saying  any relationship with earlier $X_i$ is incorporated into the value of $X_n$.  This means you have the Markov property.

Comment: Thanks! How can I write it in a fromal way ?

Answer (score 0):

For a Markov chain $P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} | X_n=x_n, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, \ldots) = P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} | X_n=x_n)$, i.e. you should be able to compute the probability distribution of $X_{n+1}$ conditioned on history by simply knowing $X_n$, independent of what happened to $X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}, ... \ldots$.

In your problem,
$X_{n+1} = f(X_n; Y_n, K, Z_n)$, i.e. $X_{n+1}$ depends on $X_n$ and a bunch of other constants/ RVs that are independent of $X$ and have identical distributions at all time steps. Thus, you can compute the probability distribution of $X_{n+1}$ conditioned on history without knowing anything about $X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}, \ldots$, i.e. $X_n$ is a Markov process.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to write it formally ? How can I go about calculating the probability distribution of X_n+1 ?